# How to count occurrence of a string in a large string and get substring till nth occurrence?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string like this:

> This a sentence from wikipedia - This is a general introduction for
>   visitors to Wikipedia. The project also has an encyclopedia article
>   about itself, Wikipedia, and some introductions for aspiring
>   contributors. For information on how to donate to the organization
>   that runs Wikipedia, see Ways to Give. @##@ This sentence is from
>   google - This is a general introduction for visitors to Wikipedia. The
>   project also has an encyclopedia article about itself, Wikipedia, and
>   some introductions for aspiring contributors. For information on how
>   to donate to the organization that runs Wikipedia, see Ways to Give.
>   @##@ This sentence is from Facebook - This is a general introduction
>   for visitors to Wikipedia. The project also has an encyclopedia
>   article about itself, Wikipedia, and some introductions for aspiring
>   contributors. For information on how to donate to the organization
>   that runs Wikipedia, see Ways to Give. @##@

Now from above string I want to count the occurrence of pattern "@##@".
and after this I want the substring till the 2nd occurrence of this pattern in the string.

So in above example the result I want is:

> Count= 3 substring = "This a sentence from wikipedia - This is a
>   general introduction for visitors to Wikipedia. The project also has
>   an encyclopedia article about itself, Wikipedia, and some
>   introductions for aspiring contributors. For information on how to
>   donate to the organization that runs Wikipedia, see Ways to Give. @##@
>   This sentence is from google - This is a general introduction for
>   visitors to Wikipedia. The project also has an encyclopedia article
>   about itself, Wikipedia, and some introductions for aspiring
>   contributors. For information on how to donate to the organization
>   that runs Wikipedia, see Ways to Give."

Can anyone please suggest me how can I do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 var splitted = text.Split(new[]{"@##@"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 var count = splitted.Count();
 var result = string.Join("@##@", splitted.Take(2).ToArray());
```

count will contain 3 and result will contain your desired string

try it [here at Ideone](http://ideone.com/RryzJf)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `Split` method.

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
  "@##@",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
| RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
| RegexOptions.Compiled
);

string[] results = regex.Split(InputText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "... wikipedia string ...";
// define n, you probably have a dynamic n or one that's defined elsewhere...
n=2;
// split the string only n times
string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] {"@##@"}, n, StringSplitOptions.None);
// show splits (use them however you want)
System.Show(parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to the `Split` method that would be more efficient on large strings:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf(this string source, string substring)
    {
        int index = -1;
        while ((index = source.IndexOf(substring, index + 1)) >= 0)
            yield return index;
    }
}
```

You could then call this like so:

```
int[] indexes = mystring.AllIndexesOf("@##@").ToArray();
int count = indexes.Length;
string substring = count > 0 ? mystring.Substring(0, indexes[0]) : mystring;
```